AppleScript to open a specific section of Terminal settings
I'm trying to open the "Profiles" section of the Terminal settings (image).

Here is my script:
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    delay 1
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "," using command down
        delay 1
        tell process "Terminal"
            click menu item "Profils" of menu "Terminal" of menu bar item "Terminal" of menu bar 1
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

But the script only opens the settings window, and not the section I want.

Once the Terminal preferences are open, try this:
tell application "Terminal"
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal"
        set w to window 1
        set bp to button "Profiles" of toolbar 1 of w
        perform action "AXPress" of bp
    end tell
end tell

You may have to change the button string to 'Profils' though.
How I got there. Note, each of the commands below will return a bunch of items. If you look through those items, you can likely figure out the next item to get the elements of.
        set w to window 1
        
        UI elements of w
        --> toolbar 1 of window "General"

        UI elements of toolbar 1 of w
        --> button "Profiles" of toolbar 1 of window "General" 

Also, you can use the click command
        click at {80, 80}
        --> button "Profiles" of toolbar 1 of window "General" of application process "Terminal" of application "System Events"     


Thanks! I just replaced set bp to button "Profiles" of toolbar 1 of w by set bp to button 2 of toolbar 1 of w to get a cross-language compatibility.

Makes sense. Glad that it worked out for you.
